# How to reduce a list of documents into a list of values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I ran an aggregation pipeline with a lookup stage on my database filtering out the data that I need and joining it with the data from another collection. I have, in the end, received something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e53b804a72bb4185c682a00"), 
    "sample_ids" : [
        {
            "sample" : ObjectId("5e4fac16ad485744e34a799c")
        }, 
        {
            "sample" : ObjectId("5e4fac18eaf0df39564a799b")
        }, 
        {
            "sample" : ObjectId("5e4fac19ad485744e34a799e")
        }, 
        {
            "sample" : ObjectId("5e4fac16eaf0df39564a799a")
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm wondering whether it is possible to "squeeze" or "reduce" the list of documents to a single list of values so that I receive something like this instead:

````
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e53b804a72bb4185c682a00"), 
    "sample_ids" : [
        ObjectId("5e4fac16ad485744e34a799c"),
        ObjectId("5e4fac18eaf0df39564a799b"),
        ObjectId("5e4fac19ad485744e34a799e"),
        ObjectId("5e4fac16eaf0df39564a799a")
    ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         sample_ids: "$sample_ids.sample"
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly was I was looking for. My knowledge of all possibilities of aggregation pipeline is still a bit hazy, so I appreciate the help.